# Sending base64 string trough sockets doesnt completely arrive

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

In my application I wanted to implement profile pictures, so I started with a standard picture, which I converted to a byte array and then base64 string, however when the client requests the string from the server it doesnt fully arrive, the server reads the whole string from the database and sends it to the client, the client receives only a part of the string, this is the string(had to use pastebin): http://pastebin.com/ZmHhsZgG And this is the string the client receives: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEA
This is how the server gets it from the database:

```
public string GetPP(string user)
    {
        CONN = new MySqlConnection();
        CONN.ConnectionString = Config.CONNSTRING;
        string query = "select * from members where username='" + user + "'";
        try
        {
            CONN.Open();
            COMMAND = new MySqlCommand(query, CONN);
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader();
            string p = null;
            while (READER.Read())
            {
                 return p = READER.GetString("profilepic");
            }
            return p;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
        finally
        {
            CONN.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

then it sends it:

```
private void Do()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[20025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;
        Responder.Responder R = new Responder.Responder();
        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                buffer = new byte[4];
                int readBytes = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
                if (readBytes == 0)
                    break;
                int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
                byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
                readBytes = networkStream.Read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
                if (readBytes == 0)
                    break;
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferreader);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                byte[] outbuffer = new byte[4];
                serverResponse = R.Respond(dataFromClient);
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                outbuffer = new byte[4];
                outbuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, 4);
                networkStream.Flush();
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("User Server >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(clNo) + " Stopped!");
    }
```

And the client receives:

```
            byte[] inbuffer = new byte[4];
            buffer = new byte[4];
            int readBytes = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
            int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(MessageSize));
            byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
            readBytes = serverStream.Read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
            string dataFromServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferreader);
            if (dataFromServer.Contains("reauth"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Session Expired! Please Re-authenticate..");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = dataFromServer; //used to see what it receives
                MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
                byte[] pData = Convert.FromBase64String(dataFromServer);
                mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
                mStream.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = bm;
            }
            clientSocket.Close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the variable 'buffer' hold in the server code? can you show that code?

Comment: Yes sorry, attached the entire code for that particular part

Comment: You're storing the return value from `NetworkStream.Read()`, but yet you seem to think that everything is received in a single `Read()` call. You must check the value of `readBytes` and keep reading until you've read the sufficient amount of bytes.

Comment: I thought I handled that with first getting a message that tells me the size of the real message, so that it knows its that big, wont it throw an exception if the message is not as big as the known size?

Comment: It would most likely throw an exception as you're converting it into a bitmap, yes. But my point is even though _you know how much data to receive_ there is no guarantee that all that will be received just because you request it. You might get for example only the first 3/4 because a single `Read()` call does **in most cases _not_** receive all the data you request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data isn't fully read because the 'buffer' variable which you send as the length indicator is not initialized to an updated value. I guess what you wanted to send was:

```
serverResponse = R.Respond(dataFromClient);
sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
outbuffer = new byte[4];
outbuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendBytes.Length);
**networkStream.Write(outbuffer , 0, 4);**
networkStream.Flush();
networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
networkStream.Flush();
```

Comment: He's also expecting everything to be received in a single `Read()` call. Could you cover that in your answer aswell? :)

Comment: Yes you are right, it works now, damn that was really stupid of me, how did I miss that, but thank you :)

Comment: First one gets the size so the second one knows how many bytes it has to read

Comment: Yes, but all data isn't likely received in a single `Read()` call. One has to check the return value of `Read()` (which is why it returns anything at all) and keep reading until you've read all the data you want.

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks, will do that too, will be a problem less :)

Answer (score 0):

NetworkStream.Read method returns the number of bytes successfully read.If you want to read whole data,you have to read several times.You can try follow codes:

```
private int read(NetworkStream ns, Byte[] data_buffer)
    {
        int result = -1;

        const int kBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[kBufferSize];
        int read_size = 0;
        int real_read_size = 0;
        int read_length;
        int total_length;

        if (ns != null && data_buffer != null)
        {
            try
            {
                total_length = data_buffer.Length;
                read_size = 0;
                real_read_size = 0;
                read_length = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    read_size = kBufferSize <= (total_length - read_length) ? kBufferSize : total_length - read_length;
                    //todo:if (ns.CanRead)
                    real_read_size = ns.Read(buffer, 0, read_size);


                    if (real_read_size > 0)
                    {
                        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, data_buffer, read_length, real_read_size);

                        read_length += real_read_size;

                        //Console.WriteLine("net Read " + read_length.ToString() + " byte!");

                        if (read_length >= total_length)
                        {
                            result = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("net Read 0 byte!");
                        result = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }



            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```